# Automatic Software Update reboots are almost always canceled

Tags: macos, iterm, auto-update

Apple's Automatic Software Updates require a reboot from time to time which is scheduled when the computer is not in use. In my case these reboots almost always fail because some non-Apple program fails to quit, mostly because the application is asking if it is allowed to quit.

I understand that these applications are not able to perfectly reproduce their state before the reboot thus asking me, to prevent data loss. But I'd still prefer a silent update over an very unlikely data loss. The programs in question are iTerm which hardly contains unsafed data in my case and sometimes MS Word which has a quite good but not perfect auto-recovery.

So I am searching for a way to make all applications quit as gracefully as possible without requiring user interaction. Answers specific to single problematic applications are also fine.

Comment: Your issue is they are non-Apple apps; all of which just auto-save & quit gracefully. Having 'usefully' pointed that out, I have no fix, sorry. Photoshop always catches my partner out too.

Comment: If it is an issue for you or your partner too, you may upvote the question.